# Set TextView in Android app after POST call

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

I am working on an android app that makes a post call to a website via API. After the call is made and returns it then puts that response in the TextView of another fragment. However every time I run the app it force closes if the fragment_main is not included in activity_main. I cannot figure out why it cannot find my ID but it is frustrating. Also if I include fragment_main in activity_main then it never goes away. Here is the code...

**MainActivity.java -------------**

```
    package com.horizonservers.horizon;

import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText;
import android.view.View;
import android.support.design.widget.NavigationView;
import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.webkit.WebViewFragment;
import android.widget.TextView;

import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.nio.Buffer;

import javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
        implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener, ProfileFragment.OnFragmentInteractionListener, MainFragment.OnFragmentInteractionListener {

    TextView mResult;

    NavigationView navigationView = null;
    Toolbar toolbar = null;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        //Set the main fragment
        MainFragment fragment = new MainFragment();
        android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction =
                    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        });

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();

        navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);


        mResult = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_result);


        // Make GET request to server
        //new 


        //Make POST request to server
        new PostDataTask().execute("https://thewebsite.com/api/v1/blah");
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        if (id == R.id.main) {
            //Set the main fragment
            MainFragment fragment = new MainFragment();
            android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction =
                    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment);
            fragmentTransaction.commit();
        } else if (id == R.id.player_profile) {
            //Set the main fragment
            ProfileFragment fragment = new ProfileFragment();
            android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction =
                    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment);
            fragmentTransaction.commit();

        } else if (id == R.id.map_tracker) {

        }

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
    }
    public void onFragmentInteraction(Uri uri){
        //you can leave it empty
    }

    class GetDataTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

        ProgressDialog progressDialog;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();

            progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
            progressDialog.setMessage("Loading Data...");
            progressDialog.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

            try {
                return getData(params[0]);
            } catch (IOException ex){
                return "Network Error!";
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

            //Set data to be shown on TextView
            mResult.setText(result);

            //cancel progressdialog
            if(progressDialog != null) {
                progressDialog.dismiss();
            }
            super.onPostExecute(result);
        }

        private String getData(String urlPath) throws IOException{


            BufferedReader bufferedReader = null;
            StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
            //Initialize request with server

            try {
                URL url = new URL(urlPath);
                HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                urlConnection.setReadTimeout(10000 /* 10 second time out */);
                urlConnection.setConnectTimeout(10000 /* 10 second time out */);
                urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
                urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-type", "application/json");
                urlConnection.connect();

                //Read data from server
                InputStream inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();
                bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
                String line;

                while((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null){
                    result.append(line).append("\n");
                }



            } finally {
                if(bufferedReader != null){
                    bufferedReader.close();
                }
            }
            return result.toString();
        }
    }


    class PostDataTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

        ProgressDialog progressDialog;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();

            progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
            progressDialog.setMessage("Inserting data...");
            progressDialog.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

            try {
                return postData(params[0]);
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                return "Network error !";
            } catch (JSONException ex) {
                return "Data Invalid !";
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);

            mResult.setText(result);

            if (progressDialog != null) {
                progressDialog.dismiss();
            }
        }

        private String postData(String urlPath) throws IOException, JSONException {

            StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
            BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = null;
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = null;

            try {
                //Create data to send to server
                JSONObject dataToSend = new JSONObject();
                dataToSend.put("apikey", "UPj07lqWdetOWrk9M8Ya9UZzeIAizjr4sYQRKzkHFYm1KaQDopytCFq9HHCerwNy");
                dataToSend.put("steamid", "STEAM_0:1:90345825");
                dataToSend.put("maptype", "surf");

                //Initialize and config request, then connect to server.
                URL url = new URL(urlPath);
                HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                urlConnection.setReadTimeout(10000 /* milliseconds */);
                urlConnection.setConnectTimeout(10000 /* milliseconds */);
                urlConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
                urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);  //enable output (body data)
                urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");// set header
                urlConnection.connect();

                //Write data into server
                OutputStream outputStream = urlConnection.getOutputStream();
                bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream));
                bufferedWriter.write(dataToSend.toString());
                bufferedWriter.flush();

                //Read data response from server
                InputStream inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();
                bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
                String line;
                while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                    result.append(line).append("&");
                }
            } finally {
                if (bufferedReader != null) {
                    bufferedReader.close();
                }
                if (bufferedWriter != null) {
                    bufferedWriter.close();
                }
            }

            return result.toString();
        }
    }


}
```

Here is MainFragment.java it inflates the fragment_main.xml file.

**FragmentMain.java**

```
package com.horizonservers.horizon;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.webkit.CookieManager;
import android.webkit.WebChromeClient;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.webkit.WebViewFragment;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;


/**
 * A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
 * Activities that contain this fragment must implement the
 * {@link MainFragment.OnFragmentInteractionListener} interface
 * to handle interaction events.
 * Use the {@link MainFragment#newInstance} factory method to
 * create an instance of this fragment.
 */
public class MainFragment extends Fragment {


    // TODO: Rename parameter arguments, choose names that match
    // the fragment initialization parameters, e.g. ARG_ITEM_NUMBER
    private static final String ARG_PARAM1 = "param1";
    private static final String ARG_PARAM2 = "param2";

    // TODO: Rename and change types of parameters
    private String mParam1;
    private String mParam2;

    private OnFragmentInteractionListener mListener;

    public MainFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    /**
     * Use this factory method to create a new instance of
     * this fragment using the provided parameters.
     *
     * @param param1 Parameter 1.
     * @param param2 Parameter 2.
     * @return A new instance of fragment MainFragment.
     */
    // TODO: Rename and change types and number of parameters
    public static MainFragment newInstance(String param1, String param2) {
        MainFragment fragment = new MainFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM1, param1);
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM2, param2);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if (getArguments() != null) {
            mParam1 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM1);
            mParam2 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM2);
        }

    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    }


    // TODO: Rename method, update argument and hook method into UI event
    public void onButtonPressed(Uri uri) {
        if (mListener != null) {
            mListener.onFragmentInteraction(uri);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
        if (context instanceof OnFragmentInteractionListener) {
            mListener = (OnFragmentInteractionListener) context;
        } else {
            throw new RuntimeException(context.toString()
                    + " must implement OnFragmentInteractionListener");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();
        mListener = null;
    }

    /**
     * This interface must be implemented by activities that contain this
     * fragment to allow an interaction in this fragment to be communicated
     * to the activity and potentially other fragments contained in that
     * activity.
     * <p/>
     * See the Android Training lesson <a href=
     * "http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html"
     * >Communicating with Other Fragments</a> for more information.
     */
    public interface OnFragmentInteractionListener {
        // TODO: Update argument type and name
        void onFragmentInteraction(Uri uri);
    }

}
```

Here is the activity_main.xml, mostly unchanged.

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <include
        layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />


    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

And finally, the fragment_main.xml

**fragment_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_result"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="-20dp"
        android:textSize="17sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:text="Test HTTP request !" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Now when I run the app without fragment_main being included in activity_main I get this error

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference
>                                                                                   at com.horizonservers.horizon.MainActivity$PostDataTask.onPostExecute(MainActivity.java:257)
>                                                                                   at com.horizonservers.horizon.MainActivity$PostDataTask.onPostExecute(MainActivity.java:228)

Can anyone help me, I'm still learning so please forgive me.

Comment: tv_result, the text view which you are using to display data in not in activity_main.xml file which you have set as content view by calling setContentView() method, so you will not get textview reference in mResult, and therefor it is showing you null pointer exception.

Comment: I tried switching from activity_main to fragment_main in setContentView however it crashes and doesn't open when I do that.

Comment: You can't switch it s like that, first let me know what you exactly want to do, 

Do you want to call web service on activity class and set result in fragment ? or you want to show fragment in activity and call web service ?

Comment: When you click the navigation item on the left it loads the fragment. When you click it it calls the PostDataTask and replaces the text view already in place.

Comment: Then no need to call web service on activity class, instead of that just execute your web service in fragment class and set value from there, so as you have bind the fragment xml file with fragment class in which the textview is there, so from fragment class you can call api and set value from there only.

Comment: Maybe but I have already been to that link. Bottom answer helped the most.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`tv_result` is in `fragment_main` and you are initializing it in your `Activity`.It needs to be initialized in your `fragment`. You cannot find the `views` of other layouts in your `activity`.

Initialize the view in your fragment's `onCreateView` like :

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
    mResult = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tv_result);
    return view;
}
```

After the on the result is obtained send it your `fragment` using eventBus or an interface and set the text in the `Fragment` and not the `Activity`.

Comment: I added @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
        mResult = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tv_result);
        return v;
    } to MainFragment, and I'm still getting the same issue.

Comment: @Destry please remove this line from your activity  mResult = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_result); and also remove mResult.setText(result);

Answer (score 0):

Okay thank you all for your help! I figured it out! I moved everything over to FragmentMain instead of MainActivity and made it inflate after it did the call! Thanks so much for your help! Here's the updated code in case someone needs it in the future.

**MainFragment**

```
package com.horizonservers.horizon;

import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;

import javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection;


/**
 * A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
 * Activities that contain this fragment must implement the
 * {@link MainFragment.OnFragmentInteractionListener} interface
 * to handle interaction events.
 * Use the {@link MainFragment#newInstance} factory method to
 * create an instance of this fragment.
 */
public class MainFragment extends Fragment {


    // TODO: Rename parameter arguments, choose names that match
    // the fragment initialization parameters, e.g. ARG_ITEM_NUMBER
    private static final String ARG_PARAM1 = "param1";
    private static final String ARG_PARAM2 = "param2";

    // TODO: Rename and change types of parameters
    private String mParam1;
    private String mParam2;

    private TextView mResult;

    private OnFragmentInteractionListener mListener;

    public MainFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    /**
     * Use this factory method to create a new instance of
     * this fragment using the provided parameters.
     *
     * @param param1 Parameter 1.
     * @param param2 Parameter 2.
     * @return A new instance of fragment MainFragment.
     */
    // TODO: Rename and change types and number of parameters
    public static MainFragment newInstance(String param1, String param2) {
        MainFragment fragment = new MainFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM1, param1);
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM2, param2);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if (getArguments() != null) {
            mParam1 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM1);
            mParam2 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM2);
        }

        new PostDataTask().execute("https://www.horizonservers.net/api/v1/PlayerInfo");
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
        mResult = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tv_result);
        return v;
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    }


    // TODO: Rename method, update argument and hook method into UI event
    public void onButtonPressed(Uri uri) {
        if (mListener != null) {
            mListener.onFragmentInteraction(uri);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
        if (context instanceof OnFragmentInteractionListener) {
            mListener = (OnFragmentInteractionListener) context;
        } else {
            throw new RuntimeException(context.toString()
                    + " must implement OnFragmentInteractionListener");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();
        mListener = null;
    }

    /**
     * This interface must be implemented by activities that contain this
     * fragment to allow an interaction in this fragment to be communicated
     * to the activity and potentially other fragments contained in that
     * activity.
     * <p>
     * See the Android Training lesson <a href=
     * "http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html"
     * >Communicating with Other Fragments</a> for more information.
     */
    public interface OnFragmentInteractionListener {
        // TODO: Update argument type and name
        void onFragmentInteraction(Uri uri);
    }

    class PostDataTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

        ProgressDialog progressDialog;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();

        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

            try {
                return postData(params[0]);
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                return "Network error !";
            } catch (JSONException ex) {
                return "Data Invalid !";
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);

            mResult.setText(result);

            if (progressDialog != null) {
                progressDialog.dismiss();
            }
        }

        private String postData(String urlPath) throws IOException, JSONException {

            StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
            BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = null;
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = null;

            try {
                //Create data to send to server
                JSONObject dataToSend = new JSONObject();
                dataToSend.put("apikey", "UPj07lqWdetOWrk9M8Ya9UZzeIAizjr4sYQRKzkHFYm1KaQDopytCFq9HHCerwNy");
                dataToSend.put("steamid", "STEAM_0:1:90345825");
                dataToSend.put("maptype", "surf");

                //Initialize and config request, then connect to server.
                URL url = new URL(urlPath);
                HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                urlConnection.setReadTimeout(10000 /* milliseconds */);
                urlConnection.setConnectTimeout(10000 /* milliseconds */);
                urlConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
                urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);  //enable output (body data)
                urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");// set header
                urlConnection.connect();

                //Write data into server
                OutputStream outputStream = urlConnection.getOutputStream();
                bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream));
                bufferedWriter.write(dataToSend.toString());
                bufferedWriter.flush();

                //Read data response from server
                InputStream inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();
                bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
                String line;
                while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                    result.append(line).append("&");
                }
            } finally {
                if (bufferedReader != null) {
                    bufferedReader.close();
                }
                if (bufferedWriter != null) {
                    bufferedWriter.close();
                }
            }

            return result.toString();
        }
    }
}
```